# iOS Background transfer using NSRULSession

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a few doubt on the background. As I have read theoretically, once all the downloads have been downloaded, **handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession** gets called. Isn't this triggering by the iOS or by the application side. Also, once each download has been completed, I read the **URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession**  will be called If the application is not running or in suspended state due to application crash or any other reason, will the app be in memory. My assumption is that if the app is in suspended state, the download controller class where the **URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession** has implemented will also not be in memory. So can anyone explain how this background operation is happening in OS level? Also I read that the app will wake up, once all the download has been downloaded. Can explain that too..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

> If an iOS app is terminated by the system and relaunched, the app can
>   use the same identifier to create a new configuration object and
>   session and retrieve the status of transfers that were in progress at
>   the time of termination. This behavior applies only for normal
>   termination of the app by the system. If the user terminates the app
>   from the multitasking screen, the system cancels all of the session’s
>   background transfers. In addition, the system does not automatically
>   relaunch apps that were force quit by the user. The user must
>   explicitly relaunch the app before transfers can begin again.

So if the app is not terminated by the user, but the app was killed for some reason (for example if iOS kills it in order to free up memory), the system will wake up your app when all tasks have finished and call the completion handler. Your `NSURLSession` background tasks (downloads and uploads) run in an OS daemon process, not in the app process, so they continue to run even if the app is killed by iOS.

Comment: Hi Nikos, Thanks for the clarification. You have explained in a pretty clear way. Do you meant the system will wake up the app, without the user tapping on the app icon or from any notification in the notification tray. I am not aware of the term OS Deamon process, but I will have a look on this. If the app wake up automatically, does that triggers by the OS Deamon process or app process.

Comment: The system wakes up your app, and calls the handler in your appDelegate where you can do whatever you need to handle the task completion (save data, refresh ui etc).

Comment: How can we test this on simulator? I tried the [Simple Background Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html) on simlator (iOS 9.0) but it did not work. It never calls `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{}`.  But the same example works in iOS 7.0. Can anybody confirm this for iOS 8.0 or greater.

Comment: Same issue for me